# Android using different icons for action bar vs options menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I'm using ActionBarSherlock in an app.  The problem I'm having is that when the device is older and the action overflow is handled by the options menu at the bottom, I need to switch the icon to accommodate that.  How can I tell if an action bar item is in the overflow or not?  Is there a selector state I can use in the drawable for that?